# How to read the table with many blocks?

Tags: arrays, fortran, spline

> > Hello everyone, Please I have a table of values of 33 rows and 15790 columns(x, f1(x),f2(x),...,f15789(x)). The first contains the values of x and the rest of those of f(X) ( 15789 f(x)). I want to read in this table, do the interpolation and then write the fitted values in an array of 128 grids points.

> > Code

```
module interpolation ! start of interpolation module.
implicit none
    real(kind = 8),dimension(:),allocatable::x,y
    real(kind = 8),allocatable::a(0:n), b(0:n), c(0:n), d(0:n)
    integer::n
end module interpolation ! end of interpolation module.

program main ! start of main program.
    use interpolation
    implicit none
    character*(*),parameter::inputdatafile = 'Tableau.dat'
    real(kind = 8)::sj, xin, f
    integer:: m, j
                

!   count data set.
    call count_data(inputdatafile,m)

!   allocate x and y arrays.
    n = m - 1 
    allocate(x(0:n),y(0:n))
    
!   load data set.
      
    call load_data(inputdatafile,n,x,y)
        x(0:32) = tab1(1:33,1)
        do i = 1, 15789
        a(0:32) = tab1(1:33, i+1)

      !  b = 0.0, c = 0.0, d = 0.0
     
   
!   allocate a, b, c, and d arrays.
    allocate(a(0:32), b(0:32), c(0:32), d(0:32))
!
    !a = y;
!
!   call natural cubic spline subroutine.
    call natural_cubic_spline(n,x,a,b,c,d)
       mat(1,1:33,i) = b(0:32)
       mat(2,1:33,i) = c(0:32)
       mat(3,1:33,i) = d(0:32)
      enddo

!   Interpolate data and write to file.
    !open(100, file = 'interpolate1.dat', action = 'write')
    xin = x(0)
    do while(xin .le. x(n))
        write(*,*))xin,f(xin)
    !   xin = xin + 0.04
    enddo
    !close(100)
    do i = 1, 15789
   b(0:32) = mat(1,1:33,i)
   c(0:32) = mat(2,1:33,i)
   d(0:32) = mat(3,1:33,i)

  open(j+90, file = 'interpolate.dat', action = 'write')

   do i=1,128 
      xin=4.0+dble(i-1)*(12.0-4.0)/(128-1)

   write(j+90,77) f(xin) 
77 format '(128e25.14)'
      enddo 
      enddo
     
!
    deallocate(x,y)
    deallocate(a, b, c, d)
!
    stop
end program main ! end of main program.

real(kind = 8) function f(xin) ! start of interpolant function f.
    use interpolation
    implicit none
    real(kind = 8),intent(in)::xin
    integer:: j, i
!
    do i = 0,n-1
        if((x(i) .le. xin).and.(xin .le. x(i+1)))then
            j = i
            exit
        endif
    enddo
!
    f = a(j) + b(j)*(xin - x(j)) + c(j)*(xin - x(j))**2 + d(j)*(xin - x(j))**3 
!
    return
end function f ! end of interpolant function f.

subroutine load_data(filename,n,x,y) ! start of load_data subroutine.
!   load data from filename.
    implicit none
    character*(*),intent(in)::filename
    integer,intent(in)::n
    real(kind = 8),dimension(0:n),intent(out)::x,y
    integer::i,ios
!
    open(100, file = filename, action = 'read')
    ios = 0; i = 0
    do while((ios .ge. 0).and.(i .le. n))
        read(100,*,iostat = ios)x(i),y(i)
        if(ios == 0)then
            i = i + 1
        endif
    enddo
    close(100)
!
    return
end subroutine load_data ! end of load_data subroutine.

subroutine count_data(filename,n) ! start of count_data subroutine.
!   This subroutine counts the number of data set in filename.
    implicit none
    character*(*),intent(in):: filename
    integer,intent(out)::n
    real(kind = 8)::x,y
    integer::ios
!
    open(100, file = filename, action = 'read')
    ios = 0; n = 0
    do while(ios .ge. 0)
        read(100,*,iostat = ios)x,y
        if(ios == 0)then
            n = n + 1
        endif
    enddo
    close(100)
!
    return
end subroutine count_data ! end of count_data subroutine.

subroutine natural_cubic_spline(n,x,a,b,c,d) ! start of natural_cubic_spline subroutine.
    implicit none
    integer,intent(in)::n
    real(kind = 8),intent(in)::x(0:n)
    real(kind = 8),intent(inout):: a(0:n)
    real(kind = 8),intent(out):: b(0:n), c(0:n), d(0:n)
    integer:: i, j
    real(kind = 8):: h(0:n), alpha(0:n), l(0:n), mu(0:n), z(0:n)
!
    h = 0.0; alpha = 0.0
!
!   step 1:
    do i = 0,n-1
        h(i) = x(i+1) - x(i)
    enddo
!
!   step 2:
    do i = 1,n-1
        alpha(i) = (3.0/h(i))*(a(i+1) - a(i)) - (3.0/h(i-1))*(a(i) - a(i-1))
    enddo
!
!   step 3:
    l(0) = 1.0; mu(0) = 0.0; z(0) = 0.0;
!
!   step 4:
    do i = 1,n-1
        l(i) = 2.0*(x(i+1) - x(i-1)) - h(i-1)*mu(i-1)
        mu(i) = h(i)/l(i)
        z(i) = (alpha(i) - h(i-1)*z(i-1))/l(i)
    enddo
!
!   step 5:
    l(n) = 1.0; z(n) = 0.0; c(n) = 0.0
!
!   step 6:
    do j = n-1,0,-1
        c(j) = z(j) - mu(j)*c(j+1)
        b(j) = (a(j+1) - a(j))/h(j) - h(j)*(c(j+1) + 2.0*c(j))/3.0
        d(j) = (c(j+1) - c(j))/(3.0*h(j))
    enddo
!
    return
end subroutine natural_cubic_spline ! end of natural_cubic_spline subroutine.
```

> > Sample data

```
     x            f1(x)                  f2(x),..., f1579(x)
    4.000        0.55977887068214E-01
    4.250        0.33301830925674E-01
    4.500        0.19357033058574E-01
    4.750        0.10851672673603E-01
    5.000        0.57601109719013E-02
    5.250        0.27793714306045E-02
    5.500        0.10812628240276E-02
    5.750        0.15097129824141E-03
    6.000       -0.32616649818477E-03
    6.250       -0.54065650568596E-03
    6.500       -0.60723892717492E-03
    6.750       -0.59463219747272E-03
    7.000       -0.54352144592126E-03
    7.250       -0.47743610751912E-03
    7.500       -0.40939905472145E-03
    7.750       -0.34605270924249E-03
    8.000       -0.29025099403574E-03
    8.250       -0.24269312486307E-03
    8.500       -0.20294374360102E-03
    8.750       -0.17005393420182E-03
    9.000       -0.14292238222802E-03
    9.250       -0.12048981961726E-03
    9.500       -0.10182978503448E-03
    9.750       -0.86178058019242E-04
   10.000       -0.72928575326720E-04
   10.250       -0.61613399268902E-04
   10.500       -0.51877242408502E-04
   10.750       -0.43452338487951E-04
   11.000       -0.36136444117556E-04
   11.250       -0.29774951350710E-04
   11.500       -0.24247094860570E-04
   11.750       -0.19455757052863E-04
   12.000       -0.15320203216670E-04
```

> > results

```
real(kind = 8),allocatable::a(0:n), b(0:n), c(0:n), d(0:n)
                                   1
Error: Explicit shaped array with nonconstant bounds at (1)
main1.f90:9:5:

  use interpolation
     1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file ‘interpolation.mod’ for reading at (1): Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions.

Comment: I changed the title because the topic you ask for is very broad. You should concentrate on the specific problem you have now and that is the error message. Once you solve that, you can move on to another work and ask about another problem.  What you cannot do is `real(kind = 8),allocatable::a(0:n), b(0:n), c(0:n), d(0:n)`, it must be `real(kind = 8),allocatable::a(:), b(:), c(:), d(:)` or `real(kind = 8)::a(0:n), b(0:n), c(0:n), d(0:n)`. You cannot combine these, allocatable requires deffered shape `(:)`. It is useful for others, that we have a duplicate with another error message now.

Comment: @VladimirFThank you, Thank you, I have corrected it, but it causes other problems.

Comment: As I said, feel free to ask a new question.